# replace character in string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, str-replace

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to play hangman. If the user guesses a certain letter, say 'p', I want to replace the underscores in 'word' at the correct indices. I am unsure how to replace the underscores with the letters correctly guessed. Thank you for your help!

e.g.

```
secretWord='apple'
word='_ _ _ _ _'
#user guesses 'p'
#word='_ p p _ _' (how word changes when the correct letters are guessed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you want something like this:

```
secret_word = 'apple'
display_word = "_" * len(secret_word)
guesses = 'p'

new_word = ""
for secret_char, display_char in zip(secret_word, display_word):
    if secret_char == guesses:
        new_word += secret_char
    else:
        new_word += display_char
display_word = new_word


print(display_word)
```

Or as a list comprehension (readblity suffers a bit):

```
secret_word = 'apple'
display_word = "_" * len(secret_word)
guess = 'p'

display_word = ''.join([secret_char if secret_char == guess else display_char for secret_char, display_char in zip(secret_word, display_word)])

print(display_word)
```